# Creating browser game with ASP.NET and HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am planning to write an ASP.NET/C# based browser game which runs on an ASP.NET server, and uses HTML 5 Canvas for graphics (2D bitmaps, no 3D graphics).

Is it possible to send Bitmaps (png/gif) and other data (a dictionary of  and 2D Array[int, string]) to the HTML 5 Canvas, and send MouseClick Coordinates back to the ASP.NET server?

Comment: The question is too general. A short answer would be "yes, it is possible" but you should ask about something specific.

Answer (score 2):

## Load a single image to canvas

You have this canvas

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Load an image by creating a new Image object and adding the image onto the canvas once the image has loaded.
The drawImage() method renders the image object onto the canvas.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var context = $("#myCanvas")[0].getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "some-image.jpg";
    img.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(img, 100, 100);
    }
</script>
```

Get the position of the mouse in the window and send the coordinates to your processing page via AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("click", function () {
        // Add a click-handler to the image.
        $("#myCanvas").bind("click", function (e) {
            var $canvas = $(e.target);
            var offset = $canvas.offset();
            var xpos = e.clientX - offset.left;
            var ypos = e.clientY - offset.top;

            $.post("Process.aspx", { x: xpos, y: ypos } );
        });
    });
</script>
```

## Load an array of images to canvas

Load an array of images and then call a function on each image when it's loaded.

The images will appear in a grid.

```
// array of images
var imgArray = [
    "image01.jpg", "image02.jpg", "image03.jpg",
    "image04.jpg", "image05.jpg", "image06.jpg",
    "image07.jpg", "image08.jpg", "image09.jpg"
];

var preArray = [];    // array of preload images
var count = 0;    // count of loaded images

for (var i in imgArray) {
    preArray[i] = new Image();
    preArray[i].src = imgArray[i];
    preArray[i].onload = function() {
        count++;
        // when the last image was loaded
        if (count == imgArray.length) {
            // draw preload array to the grid
            imageLoaded(preArray);
        }
    }
}

function imageLoaded(img) {
    // grid for canvas
    var xpos = 100;    // margin-left
    var ypos = 100;    // margin-top
    var offset = 70;    // offset for images
    var cols = 3;    // number of columns in a grid

    //creates a grid
    for(var i in img) {
        var xoffset = xpos +  offset * (i % cols);
        var yoffset = ypos +  offset * Math.floor(i / cols);
        context.drawImage(img[i], xoffset, yoffset);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Also how could I send an above mentioned [int, string] array to the Javascript?